# Very slow when getting data from class

Tags: php, oop

I have created a class, it store the data from mySQL database into class.

The performance is really slow when outputting to the browser, I have to wait like 10 seconds and this is not acceptable. How to solve this problem?

**In the controller file:**

```
$modelCategory = new modelCategory();
       $categories = $modelCategory->findAll('takeawayID = :id', array('id' => $takeawayID));
       if ($categories === false) {
               echo "Query failed";
               return;
       }
$data['categories'] = $categories;
```

**View File:**

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
    <div class="menu-container">
        <h2><?php echo $category->name; ?></h2>
        <ul class="menu-list">
    <?php foreach ($category->item as $item): ?>
            <li class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
                <div class="menu-holder">
                    <div class="text-block">
                         <div class="text-holder">
                             <?php if ($item->optionsTotal == 1): ?>
                                <?php foreach($item->options as $option):  ?>
                                   <?php $price = $option->price; ?>
                                   <?php $optionvalue = $option->optionValue; ?>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                             <?php endif; ?>
                        <h3>
                        <?php echo $item->name; ?>
                              <?php if ($item->optionsTotal == 1 && $optionvalue != "Regular"): ?>
                                 (<?php echo $optionvalue; ?>)
                               <?php endif; ?>
                         </h3>
                        <?php if ($item->desc != ""): ?>
                           <p> <?php echo $item->desc; ?> </p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                        </div>
                            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**model Category class file:**

```
<?

class modelCategory extends Model {

    public $id;
    public $desc;
    public $name;
    public $items = null;

    public function findAll($condition, $parameters) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE " . $condition;
        $statement = self::getDb()->prepare($query);
        if (!$statement->execute($parameters))
            return false;
        return self::createModels($statement->fetchAll());
    }

    public static function createModels($dataAr) {
        $models = array();
        foreach ($dataAr as $data) {
            $category = new modelCategory;
            $category->id = $data['id'];
            $category->desc = $data['description'];
            $category->name = ucwords(strtolower($data['name']));
            $models[] = $category;
        }
        return $models;
    }

    public function getItems() {
        if ($this->items === null)
            $this->items = modelItem::find('category_id = :category_id', array('category_id' => $this->id));
            return $this->items;
    }

    public function __get($key) {
        switch ($key) {
            case 'item':
                return $this->getItems();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

modelItem:: class is very similar to model Category class.

Comment: Google for xdebug - that extension will tell you which block of code and which function takes up time, how much time and how much memory. On the other hand, the culprit is probably your query, try to run it in a GUI and see whether that's what causes the whole system to be slow. On the other hand, if you have a lot of categories and if you're using an older browser - that might be the reason too.

Comment: did you try to output the query and run it in the mysql client ? does it run fast ? you should maybe add an index on the takeawayID field

Comment: I think I found a problem.  I created a test.php and added a few SQL query without any classes.  It took 13 seconds to display on the browser. The result from the class took 40 seconds! What happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one problem that I see is that you take the result and build a class to contain the data you could use PDO::FETCH_CLASS that does the same but in a more optimize way.

But like Michael J.V. said you should do some monitoring of your application to detect the exact cause of the problem (there might be multiple and not easy to catch with the eyes)

Comment: Hmm that is a good point, so how do put PDO::FETCH_CLASS into modelCategory class? Im a bit confused there.

Comment: look at the doc http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php ex#4 look like what you want

Comment: I managed to fix the problem. I added index on the itemID field, the speed dropped from 40 seconds to 0.79 Sec !! :O